# Define app is routing app using google maps ios sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to submit my app to the app store. I uploaded a geojson file to iTunes Connect because I provide directions via google maps directions API. I am now getting the following error while validating:

Invalid routing app settings. To upload a routing app coverage file on iTunes Connect, you must define the app binary as a routing app.

My two questions are:

1. Should I still define my app as a routing app if I'm not using Apple's map directions?
2. If yes, how do I define the app as a routing app in the binary?

Comment: FYI I removed the geojson file. From my research it looks like you would only turn on routing if you're using mapkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable routing mode for the app.

[image: Goto the target settings and select the Capabilities pane there you can see the option to enable routing]